# Loading multiple related entities with entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

In this query here, is there any way to reduce the

```
            .Include( c => c.EducationCredential)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.Concentration)
            .Include( c => c.EducationCredential)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.School)
            .Include(c => c.EducationCredential)
                .ThenInclude( e => e.SecondConcentration)
```

into something like

```
.Include(c => c.EducationCredential and c.Concentration and c. e.SecondConcentration)
```

Here is the full version:

```
            var cred = await _context.Credentials
            .Where( c => c.CredentialId == credentialId)

            .Include( c => c.EducationCredential)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.Concentration)
            .Include( c => c.EducationCredential)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.School)
            .Include(c => c.EducationCredential)
                .ThenInclude( e => e.SecondConcentration)

            .Include(c => c.LocationCredential)
                .ThenInclude(lc => lc.Location)

            .Include( c => c.LifeCredential)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.Topic)

            .Include(c => c.EmploymentCredential)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.Company)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return cred.Title;
```

This one is generating unnecessary joins like shown below in the sql query (notice e0, e1):

```
SELECT "c"."CredentialId", "c"."CredentialType", "c"."SorarakUserId", "c"."Title", "e"."EducationCredentialId", "e"."ConcentrationId", "e"."CredentialId", "e"."DegreeType", "e"."GraduationYear", "e"."SchoolId", "e"."SecondConcentrationId", "t"."TopicId", "t"."Category", "t"."Description", "t"."IconUrl", "t"."QuestionId", "t"."Title", "t"."TotalFollowers", "t"."UrlSlug", "e0"."EducationCredentialId", "e0"."ConcentrationId", "e0"."CredentialId", "e0"."DegreeType", "e0"."GraduationYear", "e0"."SchoolId", "e0"."SecondConcentrationId", "t0"."TopicId", "t0"."Category", "t0"."Description", "t0"."IconUrl", "t0"."QuestionId", "t0"."Title", "t0"."TotalFollowers", "t0"."UrlSlug", "e1"."EducationCredentialId", "e1"."ConcentrationId", "e1"."CredentialId", "e1"."DegreeType", "e1"."GraduationYear", "e1"."SchoolId", "e1"."SecondConcentrationId", "t1"."TopicId", "t1"."Category", "t1"."Description", "t1"."IconUrl", "t1"."QuestionId", "t1"."Title", "t1"."TotalFollowers", "t1"."UrlSlug", "l"."LocationCredentialId", "l"."CredentialId", "l"."EndYear", "l"."IsCurrentlyLivingThere", "l"."LocationId", "l"."StartYear", "t2"."TopicId", "t2"."Category", "t2"."Description", "t2"."IconUrl", "t2"."QuestionId", "t2"."Title", "t2"."TotalFollowers", "t2"."UrlSlug", "l0"."LifeCredentialId", "l0"."CredentialId", "l0"."TopicId", "t3"."TopicId", "t3"."Category", "t3"."Description", "t3"."IconUrl", "t3"."QuestionId", "t3"."Title", "t3"."TotalFollowers", "t3"."UrlSlug", "e2"."EmploymentCredentialId", "e2"."CompanyId", "e2"."CredentialId", "e2"."EndYear", "e2"."IsCurrentlyWorkingThere", "e2"."PositionTitle", "e2"."StartYear", "t4"."TopicId", "t4"."Category", "t4"."Description", "t4"."IconUrl", "t4"."QuestionId", "t4"."Title", "t4"."TotalFollowers", "t4"."UrlSlug"
    FROM "Credentials" AS "c"
    LEFT JOIN "EducationCredentials" AS "e" ON "e"."CredentialId" = "c"."CredentialId"
    LEFT JOIN "Topics" AS "t" ON "e"."ConcentrationId" = "t"."TopicId"
    LEFT JOIN "EducationCredentials" AS "e0" ON "e0"."CredentialId" = "c"."CredentialId"
    LEFT JOIN "Topics" AS "t0" ON "e0"."SecondConcentrationId" = "t0"."TopicId"
    LEFT JOIN "EducationCredentials" AS "e1" ON "e1"."CredentialId" = "c"."CredentialId"
    LEFT JOIN "Topics" AS "t1" ON "e1"."SchoolId" = "t1"."TopicId"
    LEFT JOIN "LocationCredentials" AS "l" ON "l"."CredentialId" = "c"."CredentialId"
    LEFT JOIN "Topics" AS "t2" ON "l"."LocationId" = "t2"."TopicId"
    LEFT JOIN "LifeCredentials" AS "l0" ON "l0"."CredentialId" = "c"."CredentialId"
    LEFT JOIN "Topics" AS "t3" ON "l0"."TopicId" = "t3"."TopicId"
    LEFT JOIN "EmploymentCredentials" AS "e2" ON "e2"."CredentialId" = "c"."CredentialId"
    LEFT JOIN "Topics" AS "t4" ON "e2"."CompanyId" = "t4"."TopicId"
    WHERE "c"."CredentialId" = $1
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this instead?

```
   .Include( c => c.EducationCredential.Concentration)
   .Include( c => c.EducationCredential.School)
   .Include(c => c.EducationCredential.SecondConcentration)
```

Comment: same thing. I created an issue for this on github for entity framework and it is apparently a known issue. So, we will just have to live with it until it is fixed or roll your own query.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Entity Framework Core and no work around for now. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4900